# To share a variable between two jyupter notebooks on different servers but on the same device

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i have to send a variable sql_query from and to another server
both are under different anaconda environments.

I have tried a lot but nothing has been successful. It would be really helpful we anyone could help.
I tried writing it into a file but it gets saved in its home page and cant access from the other one

Comment: Provide the reproductible code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot access the same variable from two different servers, even if they are on the same device, as the two servers are entirely separate.

I am sure that there are multiple ways to get around this, but here are some that I can think of:

HTTP requests. it would appear that Jupyter provides an API to interact with it, and this would still work if the servers where on multiple machines. https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html

TXT file on device drive. Servers access and update this.

Databases. python provides nice DB access code e.g. SQlite3

Also, Try to avoid posting things like your IP address on the internet -> there are some nasty people here.